# VBA: Search column for first instance of string and assign to new array or string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that contains mixed strings and I need to find all the unique strings and declare to either a string or array variable. The last row of the column will vary so I cannot use a definite range. I was thinking of using some form of string comparison of the preceding cell and current cell, but like I said the data is mixed so when redundant data comes up this complicates the problem. Here is a picture to try and explain it better.
EDIT: The string concatenation I will worry about that later.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Excel 365.

With data in **A1** through **A11**, in another cell enter:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A11)
```

to get:

[image]

or:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,UNIQUE(A1:A11))
```

to get a comma-separated list:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

With VBA, try this UDF:

```
Public Function unikue(rng As Range)
    Dim arr, c As Collection, r As Range
    Dim nCall As Long, nColl As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    
    nCall = Application.Caller.Count
    
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each r In rng
            c.Add r.Text, CStr(r.Text)
        Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
    nColl = c.Count
    
    
    If nCall > nColl Then
        ReDim arr(1 To nCall, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To nCall
            arr(i, 1) = ""
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim arr(1 To nColl, 1 To 1)
    End If
    
    For i = 1 To nColl
        arr(i, 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i
    
    unikue = arr
End Function
```

Comment: @ian.templeton  see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: No problem doing this in VBA as the above Excel formula result can be written to any cell using VBA via `Evaluate()` (not forgetting double quotations marks within the string to be evaluated:-)